# Venn diagram drawing!

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What would a Venn Diagram look like for $\bar{C}-D$?

I have drawn an outline of a rectangle for Universal Set, a circle for $C$ and a circle for $D$, the circles intersect.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question!

Comment: All answers are good! Each in their own way, one is visual while the others explain with words! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I like to give hints for such questions, but I am not sure I can without simply giving away the answer, so [here it is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(complement%20of%20C)%20setminus%20D).

Try to understand the answer by drawing two separate pictures: one for $\bar{C}$ and one for $D$. See if you can "combine" the two pictures to arrive at the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying different ways to figure it out and kept arriving at that answer. Just wasn't completely sure it was right. I'll keep that method in mind as it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you can imagine that $$\bar C \text{ is "everything but $C$}",$$and $$\bar C - D \text{ is "[everything but C] but D"},$$ and that is clearly "everything except [$C$ or $D$]".

That is, $$\bar C - D = \Omega - (C \cup D),$$ where $\Omega$ is the "Universal Set".

Comment: That's a good explanation as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also think of it as $$\overline{C}-D=\overline{C\cup D}$$

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's good too!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Maxima CAS, I have written a function vennplot for this,[image]

For how it has been written, [check this](https://www.academia.edu/33992403/Venn_Diagram_Plotting_using_Maxima_CAS)